# VBA Message Box when Row is added/deleted but only once

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a message box that tells you to open some other files before adding/deleting rows to make sure references aren't lost. The below works but it works every time a row is added, is it possible to show only once when the first row is added/deleted? Any help is much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then
    MsgBox "If File 1 and File 2 are not open, please close this workbook without saving and open all files first."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is declare a `Boolen` type public variable. See below codes. Message will be displayed once after open the file. If file is closed and re-open then once again will show message for one time.

```
Public StopPopMsg As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not StopPopMsg Then
        If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then
            MsgBox "If File 1 and File 2 are not open, please close this workbook without saving and open all files first."
            StopPopMsg = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic Harun, worked like a charm. Muchly appreciated for your quick answer.

Comment: @FBeckenbauer4 Glad to know!